# Why my function not work ( set 2 decimal number) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my function not work ( set 2 decimal number) using javascript ?

http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/102/

when fill number, my code will set 2 decimal your number.

```
EG fill 123 will alert 123.00
   fill 123.1 will alert 123.10
   fill 123.1234 will alert 123.12
```

But not work , how can i do that ?

```
<input type="text" id="xxx" onchange="fn_1()"/> 


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function fn_1()
    {   
        var xxx_val = document.getElementById('xxx').value
        var n = xxx_val.indexOf(".");
        var res = xxx_val.replace(".", "");
        var res_length = res.length;
        var decimal_length = (res_length - n);

    if(n != '-1')
    {
        if(decimal_length > '1')
        { 
            // 2 decimal and morethan //
            //var x = parseFloat(Math.round(xxx_val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            var x = Math.floor(xxx_val * 100) / 100
        }
        else
        {
            // 1 decimal //
            var x = xxx_val.toFixed(2)
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // not decimal //
       var x = xxx_val.toFixed(2)
    }

    alert(x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: (123.4).toFixed(2).replace(/\.(\d{1})$/,".$1"+"0");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `xxx_val` is a string not a number, so it doesn't have methods like `toFixed()`

```js
function fn_1() {
  var xxx_val = document.getElementById('xxx').value
  var n = xxx_val.indexOf(".");
  var res = xxx_val.replace(".", "");
  var res_length = res.length;
  var decimal_length = (res_length - n);

  if (n != '-1') {
    if (decimal_length > '1') {
      // 2 decimal and morethan //
      //var x = parseFloat(Math.round(xxx_val * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
      var x = Math.floor(+xxx_val * 100) / 100
    } else {
      // 1 decimal //
      var x = (+xxx_val).toFixed(2)
    }
  } else {
    // not decimal //
    var x = (+xxx_val).toFixed(2)
  }

  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="xxx" onchange="fn_1()" />
```